# Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Local VB.Net 2010 ProcessingException was unhandled Message=An error occurred during local report processing

Tags: .net, vb.net-2010

I have this error VB.Net 2010

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred during local report processing.

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
```

Public Class General_cousre_1_Degrees_One

```
Private Sub General_cousre_1_Degrees_One_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim para1 As New ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", St_Num.Text)


    Me.General_Course_1_TableAdapter_One.Fill(Me.DATABASEDataSet.General_Course_1_One, St_Num.Text)

    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {para1})

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you I have solved the error**

**The ReportViewer was empty**

I filled the Report Data Source & Report Data Instance

ReportViewer

1- choose ReportViewer Task

2- Choose Data Source

3- fill Report Data Source

4- fill Report Data Instance